# How to remove "//" from csv record on first column only

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Previously I asked on how to add `//`.
Now I need to remove `//` from the first column.

**Sample File1**

```
// some comment
// some  explanation
//===================
100,5,3,8,,//NA,
500,5,44,8,,,
2500,5,2,8,,//22,
//2121,5,2,8,,,
5535,5,4,6069,,,
//5844,1,4,5844,,,
5900,5,2,8,,,
//6069,5,4,8,,,
```

**Result**

```
// some comment
// some  explanation
//===================
100,5,3,8,,//NA,
500,5,44,8,,,
2500,5,2,8,,//22,
2121,5,2,8,,,
5535,5,4,6069,,,
5844,1,4,5844,,,
5900,5,2,8,,,
6069,5,4,8,,,
```

I tried with

```
sed 's/\/\///1'
```

and

```
awk -F',' '/\/\/[0-9][0-9][0-9]*/ {sub ("//", ""); print}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
sed -E 's|^//([0-9])|\1|' file
```

or with standard sed

```
sed 's|^//\([[:digit:]]\)|\1|' file
```

or

```
awk '/^\/\/[0-9]/{sub(/^\/\//,"")}1' file
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this work great..

Comment: The `+` is redundant. `sed 's|^//\([[:digit:]]\)|\1|' file` would be equivalent (and standard).

Comment: Indeed, thanks @StéphaneChazelas. Removed the `+` and added your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below Sed command and worked fine

command

```
sed '4,$s/^\/\///g' filename

// some comment
// some  explanation
//===================
100,5,3,8,,//NA,
500,5,44,8,,,
2500,5,2,8,,//22,
2121,5,2,8,,,
5535,5,4,6069,,,
5844,1,4,5844,,,
5900,5,2,8,,,
6069,5,4,8,,,
```